# How can I select the last timestamp reading per day for multiple user id's and multiple days?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database that contains user id, calories burned (value), and the timestamp at which those calories burned were recorded(reading_date). An individual could have multiple calorie readings for the same day, but I'm only interested in the last reading since it's a total of all the previous readings for that day.

IN:

```
SELECT 
  DISTINCT ON (date, user_contents.content_id)
  date_trunc('day',reading_date + time '05:00') date,
   user_id,
   created_at,
   value
FROM data
```

OUT:

```
date                | user_id |  created_at            | value
2019-01-13 00:00:00 | 138     | 2019-01-18 06:07:52    | 81.0
2019-01-15 00:00:00 | 137     | 2019-01-15 15:43:25    | 87.0
2019-01-16T00:00:00 | 137     | 2019-01-18 04:22:11    | 143.0
2019-01-16T00:00:00 | 137     | 2019-01-18 06:12:11    | 230.0
additional values omitted
```

I want to be able to select the maximum reading value for each day per person. I've tried using DISTINCT statements such as:

```
SELECT
DISTINCT ON (date, user_contents.content_id)
  date_trunc('day',reading_date + time '05:00') date,
```

Sometimes that results in an error message:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions
```

Sometimes it filters out some results, but isn't always giving me the last reading of the day or only one result per person per day.

My optimal end result would look like this (the third record having been removed):

```
date                | user_id |  created_at            | value
2019-01-13 00:00:00 | 138     | 2019-01-18 06:07:52    | 81.0
2019-01-15 00:00:00 | 137     | 2019-01-15 15:43:25    | 87.0
2019-01-16T00:00:00 | 137     | 2019-01-18 06:12:11    | 230.0
additional values omitted
```

Ultimately, I'm going to use this data to sum up the value column and determine the total number of calories burned by everyone in the dataset over a time period.

Comment: Your code is not MySQL code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be  using Postgres.

Follow the instructions in the error message.  You want something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_id, reading_date::date)
       date_trunc('day',reading_date + time '05:00') date,
       user_id, created_at,value
FROM data
ORDER BY user_id, reading_date::date DESC, reading_date DESC
```